# Copy values (except 0) from array 2 to array 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays with the same shape. Now I want to copy all values, except 0, from array 2 to array 1.

**array 1:**

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

**array 2:**

```
[0, 2, 0]
[4, 0, 0]
[6, 6, 0]
```

The result should now look like this:

```
[1, 2, 1]
[4, 1, 1]
[6, 6, 1]
```

*How is this possible in Python?*

Answer (score 13):

[`nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) will return the indices of an array that is not 0.

```
idx_nonzero = B.nonzero()
A[idx_nonzero] = B[idx_nonzero]
```

`nonzero` is also what `numpy.where` returns when only a condition is passed in. Thus, equivalently, we can do

```
idx_nonzero = np.where(B != 0)  # (B != 0).nonzero()
A[idx_nonzero] = B[idx_nonzero]
```

This solution is in-place. If you need to create a new array, see [@jp_data_analysis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48501484/9209546).

Answer (score 9):

`np.where` supports this. Below solution creates a new array. For an in-place alternative, see [@Tai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502866/9209546).

```
A = np.array(
[[1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1]])

B = np.array(
[[0, 2, 0],
[4, 0, 0],
[6, 6, 0]])

C = np.where(B==0, A, B)

# [1, 2, 1]
# [4, 1, 1]
# [6, 6, 1]
```